# Operation on each row from select query

Tags: sql, postgresql

How execute additional query (UPDATE) on each row from SELECT?
I have to get amount from each row from select and send it to user's balance table.

Example:

```
status 0 - open
status 1 - processed
status 2 - closed
```

My select statement:

```
select id, user_id, sell_amount, sell_currency_id
from (select id, user_id, sell_amount, sell_currency_id,
             sum(sell_amount) 
             over (order by buy_amount/sell_amount ASC, date_add ASC) as cumsell
      from market t
      where (status = 0 or status = 1) and type = 0
     ) t
where 0 <= cumsell and 7 > cumsell - sell_amount;
```

Select result from market table

```
id;user_id;amount;status
4;1;1.00000000;0
6;2;2.60000000;0
5;3;2.00000000;0
7;4;4.00000000;0
```

We get 7 amount and send it to user balance table.

```
id;user_id;amount;status
4;1;0.00000000;2 -- took 1, sum 1, status changed to 2
6;2;0.00000000;2 -- took 2.6, sum=3.6, status changed to 2
5;3;0.00000000;2 -- took 2, sum 5.6, status changed to 2
7;4;2.60000000;1 -- took 1.4, sum 7.0, status changed to 1 (because there left 2.6 to close)
```

User's balance table

```
user_id;balance
5;7 -- added 7 from previous operation
```

Postgres version 9.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general principle is to use `UPDATE ... FROM` over a subquery. Your example is too hard to turn into useful `CREATE TABLE` and `SELECT` statements, so I've made up a quick dummy dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE balances (user_id integer, balance numeric);
INSERT INTO balances (user_id, balance) VALUES (1,0), (2, 2.1), (3, 99);
CREATE TABLE transactions (user_id integer, amount numeric, applied boolean default 'f');
INSERT INTO transactions (user_id, amount) VALUES (1, 22), (1, 10), (2, -10), (4, 1000000);
```

If you wanted to apply the transactions to the balances you would do something like:

```
   BEGIN;

   LOCK TABLE balances IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
   LOCK TABLE transactions IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;

   UPDATE balances SET balance = balance + t.amount 
   FROM (
      SELECT t2.user_id, sum(t2.amount) AS amount 
      FROM transactions t2 
      GROUP BY t2.user_id
   ) t 
   WHERE balances.user_id = t.user_id;

   UPDATE transactions
   SET applied = true
   FROM balances b
   WHERE transactions.user_id = b.user_id;
```

The `LOCK` statements are important for correctness in the presence of concurrent inserts/updates.

The second `UPDATE` marks the transactions as applied; you might not need something like that in your design.